# Why didn't the magicians try to repeat the other plagues?

Tags: yetziat-mitzrayim, plagues-makkos

After the Magicians failed to produce lice, did the magicians try to do the rest of the plagues?

If yes, why didn't the scripture mention it?

If no, why didn't they try to do so?

Comment: I think once they realized and accepted that this was God's work (and Moshe really was His messanger), there was no reason for them to keep trying to replicate the makkos- they already know that what Moshe was doing was coming from hashem

Comment: @Lo ani - If they really recognize that this was God's work and they can do nothing, why are they still hardening their hearts and not letting Israelites go?

Comment: They understand it's God's work, but either they deny His all-encompassing power and control, or they did accept letting the Israelites go (like they said later to Par'o, "for how long will you deny them..."), and it was just Par'o who hardened his heart